# Adding a char into a temporaryChar outputting garbage

Tags: c++, char

I'm doing a method in which I load a notepad file with random data in it, and I have to read character by character. Then I check whether this character is a Digit or a Letter and so on and so forth.

I invented a method called isDigit (ch) in which it accepts the character that is being loaded and checks whether it is between 0 and 9. If it is a Digit it is added to a newly created `char tempString`.

The **Problem** is that whenever I add to this `char tempString` the first number comes out OK but the rest (in my dummy file I have from 1 - 5) it comes out as garbage.

What could be the reason please? Down below you have the code and the output

---

### Coding

```
Token Lexer::getNextToken()
{
    char ch;
    char tempString;

    std::ifstream input("dummyData.txt");

    while (input)
    {
        input.get(ch);

        if(isDigit(ch))
        {
            tempString += ch;
            cout << tempString << endl;
            Col++;
        }
        else if (ch == '\n')
        {
            cout << "\nNew Line\n" << endl;
            Row++;
            Col = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error" << endl;
        }

        Offset ++;

        cout << " Row " << Row << " Column " << Col << " Offset: " << Offset << endl;
    }

    return Token::tkDigit;
}
```

[image: Garbage Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `tempString` as a single character, rather than a string. Adding a character to it doesn't turn it into a string and append the character; it adds the ASCII value of `ch` to the value already in `tempString`, producing some other character value.

Try `std::string tempString;`

Comment: Thanks Worked like a Charm

Answer (score 1):

You use `char tempString` as a buffer, but instead to store data in it you increment its value which results as a rubbish. Notice that char which presents a digit is not a digit value you expect. This way you go outside printable string boundary.

Answer (score 1):

`tempString` is defined as a `char`. I believe you want it to be a `std::string`.

In addition you should use standard functions instead of rewriting from scratch. See [std::isdigit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit).

Comment: it's a must by our lecturer to use our made stuff, as we are doing a compiler. Thanks for your help

Comment: Why don't you use your own `std::ifstream` them? Ask him next time.